# 30 second cron does not end execution

Tags: php, cron

I have this Cron (Split into multiple lines for readability)

```
8,18,28,38,48,58 * * * * 
/usr/local/bin/setlock 
-n /tmp/cronlock.1618472.147531 sh 
-c $'/home/ryannaddy/trendie.co/get/next_trends'
```

It runs this file:

```
#!/usr/local/php54/bin/php-cgi -q
<?php
set_time_limit(90);
require_once __DIR__ . "/../includes/setup.php";
$db   = new Database();

$lock = (bool)$db->getOne("select get_lock('get_trends', 0)");
// File is already running; don't run again.
if(!$lock){
    echo "Lock Exists\n";
    exit;
}

$trendie = new Trendie();
$trendie->prepare();

$trendie->setNextId();
$trendie->getCandidates();
$trendie->selectFinal();

$db->getOne("select release_lock('get_trends')");
```

For some reason, the cron doesn't always end, it can run for hours, but it shouldn't. On average it runs in about 30 seconds successfully, but from time to time it doesn't end, and I have to manually log into my server and kill the process to allow it to run.

I have attempted to remove the mysql `get_lock`, but that doesn't fix it. I also added the `set_time_limit(90)`, and that doesn't fix it either. The `$trendie->getCandidates` method does lots of `http` requests (15-20) either using a website's API or `file_get_contents()` depending on the application. But as stated before they usually all end within 30 seconds.

So... Why isn't this being limited to 90 seconds `set_time_limit(90);` if it takes too long to run?

I have the cron set to email me any output, and I am getting this when it doesn't work:

```
setlock: fatal: unable to lock /tmp/cronlock.1618472.147531: temporary failure
```

Comment: Look at the timeout program and use that in your cronjob, it will ensure your script is terminated if it runs on forever http://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout - Also are you running in safe mode as set_time_limit will not work in safe mode

Comment: you might be able to circumvent having to do locks here by running all of the sql in a transaction. see http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.transactions.php Note that transaction support depends upon storage engine. On engines that don't support transaction the begin transaction call will silently no do nothing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What I did, was I created another cron, one that runs 1 minute before this one with this code in it:

```
#!/bin/sh
pkill -f next_trends
```

So far it has worked like a charm!

Comment: If it works then the original cron job shouldn't be locking in the first place.